# How do I place the Angular bootstrap ui <tabset> heading component to the bottom after the content rather than at the top?

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-tabset

My code looks like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Tab1">content 1</tab>
    <tab heading="Tab2">content 2</tab>
    <tab heading="Tab3">content 3</tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code creates the default tabset as demonstrated by this plunker code :

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&s=gYWtjBltWXYqhczs

[image: I want my tabset to look like as in this picture with the tab heading at the bottom]

I want my tabset to look like as in this picture with the tab heading at the bottom.

Please guide how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself after a lot of digging as to what the  and  tags render into on page load in the browser:

This strip of jquery code will do the job for you :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timex = setInterval(function(){
        if($(".tab-content").html()){
            clearInterval(timex);
            $('div.tab-content').insertBefore($('div.tab-content').prev('ul'));
        }
    },1);

});
</script>
```